# Mapbox NavigationViewOptions and NavigationLauncherOptions

Tags: javascript, java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm new with Mapbox and I already have a few days trying to figure out how can I add a progressChangeListener to my NavigationLauncherOptions.

Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
    Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(-80.311641,25.910195);
    Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(-80.312159, 25.911922);

    NavigationRoute.builder(MainActivity.this)
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(originPoint)
            .destination(destinationPoint)
            .build()
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                    currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);
                    NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                            .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                            .shouldSimulateRoute(true)
                            .build();
                    NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);

                    NavigationViewOptions.Builder optionsNavigate = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
                    optionsNavigate.progressChangeListener(new ProgressChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
                            Log.v("RES", String.valueOf(routeProgress.currentState()));
                            if (routeProgress.currentState().equals(RouteProgressState.ROUTE_ARRIVED)) {
                                // Execute arrival logic
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable throwable) {
                }
            });
```

I try the code attached but it doesn't work.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Would you please go into detail as to what does not work?

Comment: It work fine, but when I add  NavigationViewOptions.Builder optionsNavigate = NavigationViewOptions.builder(); to capture the progress change it doesn't do nothing

Comment: I need to capture and Log the progressChange to do something else an the arrival.Thank you

Comment: I'm doing my navigation using NavigationLauncherOptions but I don't know how to add NavigationViewOptions to do the progressChangeListener

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/route-progress/#navigation-ui-sdk) in Mapbox's route progress documentation for the Navigation UI SDK:

> This listeners is only available if you are adding `NavigationView` to
>   your `Activity` or `Fragment` layout XML via `NavigationViewOptions`. You
>   are not able to add them to `NavigationLauncherOptions`.

As such, I'd recommend adding the `NavigationView` via `NavigationViewOptions` rather than `NavigationLauncherOptions` and following the detailed guidance in Mapbox's [route progress documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/route-progress/), if you need access to the progress listeners. The [`mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/) example app also provides some useful examples.

Comment: Thank you so much, your comment was really useful.

Comment: Glad to hear this is helpful!